# How can i pass dynamic converted date to html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, momentjs, ejs

I have my count down div like below : Here i have to set data-countdown with dynamic date variable which comes from mmongodb. I am using ejs template to store that in below script and convert it into required formate then need to send it below html

```
 <div class="countdown" data-countdown="2021/07/10 18:00:00">
                            <div class="days">
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <span>days</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hours">
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <span>hours</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="minutes">
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <span>minutes</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="seconds">
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <span>seconds</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I am passing user input from data bast to ejs html element for that i have following script. I am getting the data formate from DB as "Mon Jul 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530" and i am converting using below script to match the formate "2021/07/10 18:00:00". My problem is how can i send below formatted date  to above "data-countdown" attribute in html.

one more doubt is How can i pass ejs variable into below script. Is it working if i pass same as below.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var ds = "<%=My Date as per DB%>"; // Here my dynamic data comes from mongodb database.
    var date = moment(new Date(ds.substr(0, 16)));
    date.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can can achieve that from the server side using ejs syntax 
In your ejs page

```
data-countdown= "<%= typeof date != 'undefined'||'' ? date:'' %>"
```

your code has to be placed in the server

```
var ds =        // retrieve date from mongodb database.
    var date = moment(new Date(ds.substr(0, 16)));
    const date=date.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"));
pass the date to your ejs template

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('page name',date)
}
```

Comment: var ds = "<%=My Date as per DB%>";  my variable not coming to this template

Comment: try and do it from the server